# PyInstaller : Unable to find "/usr/sbin/neato" when adding binary and data files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

i made a pyqt5 translator app , it works fine from the interpreter ,

[image]

knowing that i use **kali linux & pyqt5 & qt designer & pyinstaller == 4.9 .**

i ran this command on my terminal :

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --noconsole translator.py`

and finally i got this error with no output

**461922 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'gtk'**

**461923 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'PySide'**

**461943 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygraphviz.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...**

**Unable to find "/usr/sbin/neato" when adding binary and data files.**

i installed gtk and pyside2 and pyside6 , and it didn't work , and i couldn't install "pyside".

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cx_freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/)
Install using `python3 -m pip install --upgrade cx_Freeze`
Here is the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/script.html#script).

Run `cxfreeze -c translator.py --target-dir dist` and you should get an application without errors.

This error that you are seeing is likely due to PyInstaller not being able to perceive the directory where the layouts are being stored correctly. I shared this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78014447/17473546) as well. I don't think there is a fix for this at this time. I have raised the issue with their GitHub repository as well.