# PyInstaller: Unable to find '/usr/sbin/neato' when adding binary and data files

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using PySide6 and pygraphviz to create a simple three widget desktop application. When I use `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole stackedAPP.py`, PyInstaller throws me this error: `Unable to find '/usr/sbin/neato' when adding binary and data files.` It seems that PyInstaller cannot find any of the pygraphviz layouts, not just neato because I tried using other layouts too. This is not an isolated issue, as I found [in this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172910/pyinstaller-unable-to-find-usr-sbin-neato-when-adding-binary-and-data-files), but there was no answer so I had to ask again.
A similar PyInstaller error [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2159) seemed to have been resolved after modifying the hooks for the package, so I tried to look into hook-pygraphviz.py.

It seemed to me that the error lies in the line: `graphviz_bindir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(shutil.which("dot")))` which returns `/usr/sbin`

Upon further investigation, I found that `shutil.which('dot')` returns `/usr/bin/dot` which is actually correct (having manually confirmed it). But the result of `os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/dot')` is actually something else entirely:

```
>>> import os
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.which("dot")
'/usr/bin/dot'
>>> os.path.realpath('/usr/bin/dot')
'/usr/sbin/libgvc6-config-update'
```

So the reason why PyInstaller cannot find neato in /usr/sbin is because it is not in /usr/sbin, and this is why it is searching in /usr/sbin in the first place.
So I decided to manually modify the hook and set the path as `graphviz_bindir = '/usr/bin'`
This helped and PyInstaller compiled successfully, but when I use the application, it crashes when it enters the stage where it is using pygraphviz and this is the error message I see:

```
(stackedAPP:18070): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:02:47.490: GFileInfo created without standard::icon

(stackedAPP:18070): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:02:47.490: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1766 (g_file_info_get_icon): should not be reached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processUI.py", line 127, in on_finished
  File "processUI.py", line 189, in generate_causal_loop_diagram
  File "pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1613, in draw
  File "pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1404, in _run_prog
OSError: Warning: Could not load "/tmp/_MEIsRtebz/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - file not found
Warning: Could not load "/tmp/_MEIsRtebz/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - file not found
Warning: Could not load "/tmp/_MEIsRtebz/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - file not found
Warning: Could not load "/tmp/_MEIsRtebz/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - file not found
Warning: Could not load "/tmp/_MEIsRtebz/graphviz/libgvplugin_gd.so.6" - file not found
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: bmp canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json eps fig gd gd2 gif gtk gv ico imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg json json0 mp pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tif tiff tk vdx vml vmlz vrml wbmp webp x11 xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json xlib
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I am using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu-23.10 on which I am running this process. When I installed graphviz and pygraphviz I used:

```
sudo apt-get graphviz graphviz-dev
pip install pygraphviz
```

as recommended in this [documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the result of `which neato` ?  If it is installed (by apt-get), **which** will tell you where it is

Comment: @sroush `which neato` also gives `/usr/bin/neato`

Comment: I apologize for not reading to the end.  try `echo 'graph {a -- b}'|neato`  does the result include height=0.5 ?  If so neato seems to be working correctly (no missing pango libraries)

Comment: @sroush Yes height is 0.5:

```graph {
 graph [bb="0,0,125.21,46.639"];
 node [label="\N"];
 a [height=0.5,
  pos="27,28.639",
  width=0.75];
 b [height=0.5,
  pos="98.21,18",
  width=0.75];
 a -- b [pos="53.516,24.677 59.368,23.803 65.572,22.876 71.434,22"];
}
```
neato seems to be working fine. But when I use PyInstaller that's when the issue starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found to just get an application is to use [cx_freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/)

I ran `cxfreeze -c translator.py --target-dir dist` and got an application that runs without any errors. I'll have to take a look how cx_Freeze does things differently from PyInstaller.

It's also possible to use pyinstaller, but I had to modify `hooks/stdhooks/hook-pygraphviz.py` slightly. I modified the line `graphviz_bindir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(shutil.which("dot")))` to `graphviz_bindir = shutil.which('dot')` and added dynamic graphviz libs by locating where graphviz was and then using --add-binary argument from pyinstaller. For me it was something like `pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/graphviz:graphviz main.py`.